# Charging many Qi devices

Tags: wireless, power

I have about 30 small (70mm x 50mm) "tags" that are used for tracking objects in a real-time location system (RTLS).  The tags can be recharged using Qi wireless charging.  Is there a charging pad available that can charge many (say 10 or more) of these tags at the same time?